# Parse through variable in python

Tags: python, telnet

I'm wanting to store a telnet output in a string variable and parse through it to get the information i need, similar to if i was to output it to a file and parse through it (This way I don't need to).

At the moment I am trying to use the "for line" argument as I would with a text document, but it does not seem to recognize separate lines in the variable (whether the string variable removes formatting or not I'm not sure).

All the Telnet scripts work correctly as I have previously outputted them into text files and parsed through them that way, I'm just trying to eliminate a step.

Here's an example of the telnet get request

```
tn.write("SomeCommand::SOMEPARAMETERS;\n")
tn.read_until(" EN=0   ENDESC=Succeeded.", TIMEOUT)
output = tn.read_very_eager()
```

Here's an example of the telnet output

```
Description of Information
-----------------------------------------
Name1     Name2      Name3      Name4      
example1  exampe2    example3   example4
-----------------------------------------
```

Here's what I have written to try and and parse through this.

```
array = []

for line in output:  # Read lines from CPU MEM TEMP
    if "example1" in line:
        for word in line.split():
            array.append(word)

Name1 = array[0]
Name2 = array[1]
Name3 = array[2]
Name4 = array[3]

print (Name1 + Name2 + Name3, etc....)
```

Can anyone shed some light on wheter I have the right Idea with this or does it need to be done a completely diffrent way to simply parsing through a txt file (which i have working using similar code)

Thanks all

Comment: are you sure that `read_very_eager` returns a list of lines? If it returns the whole text as one string, then `for line in output` is actually checking one character at a time. In this case you'd have to split it in lines first.

Comment: Hmmm, it seems you are right. I just tested It then only searching for "e" (as in start of example) and it returned it

Comment: How would I go about splitting it into lines first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the output in lines first (I'm assuming the lines are separated by a newline):

```
for line in output.splitlines():  # Read lines from CPU MEM TEMP
    if "example1" in line:
        for word in line.split():
            array.append(word)
```

(Edit: replaced `.split('\n')` with `.splitlines()` as per @PaulMcGuire 's suggestion)

Comment: Consider using `output.splitlines()` instead of `output.split('\n')`. `splitlines` takes care of Windows vs. Unix EOLs, *and* doesn't require any ugly backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with regular expressions:

```
import re

array = []

lines = output.split('\n')

for line in lines:  # Read lines from CPU MEM TEMP
    if re.search('example1', line):
        line = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', line)
        for word in line.split(' '):
            array.append(word)

print array
```

This code prints the next output:

```
['example1', 'exampe2', 'example3', 'example4']
```

Comment: Thanks for our answer man. Does this have an advantage to the way I'm doing it at the moment. I'm worried that if a value comes up as null (through telnet), the script will grab the wrong value, which i assume regular expressions will help with.

Comment: I think it doesn't have any advantage to your way. To be honest, my solution is based in a misunderstanding of the `split()` method (I'm new to Python xD). I think @Roberto has the correct solution, as you've marked. However, regular expressions can be more versatile so, in the future, you could need them for these parsing applications.